# Access files in a directory and write the file paths to a text file in ascending order using PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of video files in my server. I would like to list out all the video files in this directory and write it to a text file. These video files are all having the same name output-x.mp4, and x is the number from 0 to an unknown figure. The total number of video files is dynamic and therefore I don't get to know the number of the last video. I have the below code to access all the video files in this directory. It works fine with only one problem: The video files written to the text file are not sorted in ascending order.

```
$directory = "video/myvideo";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."Path/to/text/file", "wb");
$split_video_files = scandir($directory);
foreach($split_video_files as $file)
{
    $content = "file ".$directory.$file."\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $content);
}
fclose($fp);
```

What the text file gave me is this:

```
video/myvideo/output-0.mp4
video/myvideo/output-1.mp4
video/myvideo/output-10.mp4
video/myvideo/output-11.mp4
video/myvideo/output-12.mp4
video/myvideo/output-13.mp4
video/myvideo/output-14.mp4
video/myvideo/output-2.mp4
video/myvideo/output-3.mp4
video/myvideo/output-4.mp4
video/myvideo/output-5.mp4
video/myvideo/output-6.mp4
video/myvideo/output-7.mp4
video/myvideo/output-8.mp4
video/myvideo/output-9.mp4
```

It lists out all the filename that start with "1" first before proceed to "2" and so on. Any ways for me to sort it in ascending order so that it starts from 0, 1, 2,…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`natsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) array sorting function [DEMO](http://ideone.com/0U6sxu)

```
natsort($split_video_files);
```